# How do you retrieve the request body of a POST when creating an HTTP server using the java Apache httpcore5 framework

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I am creating an HTTP server using the [Apache httpcore5 framework](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/index.html).  I am implementing an `AsyncServerRequestHandler`.  The method I implement is

```
public void handle(Message<HttpRequest, ?> message, ResponseTrigger responseTrigger, HttpContext httpContext)
```

Unfortunately, the `message` I am passed returns `null` if I call `getBody()` .  I need that body because it contains the CGI arguments of a POST.

(edit): my prepare() method looks like

```
public AsyncRequestConsumer<Message<HttpRequest, Void>> prepare(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)
//        throws HttpException
{
    return new BasicRequestConsumer<Void>(new NoopEntityConsumer());
}
```

For people who are speed-reading this: I am the server.  I am not asking how a client performs a POST.   I am asking how a server gains access to the POST body so it can properly respond.
How do I get that message body?

Comment: What does your `prepare(...)` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Kelley's question led me to figure out the problem.  By switching to`implements AsyncServerRequestHandler<Message<HttpRequest, byte[]>>`
and rewriting my `prepare()` as

```
public AsyncRequestConsumer<Message<HttpRequest, byte[]>> prepare(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)
{
    if (request.getMethod().equals("GET"))
        return new BasicRequestConsumer(new NoopEntityConsumer()); // is that one client bananas?

    AsyncEntityConsumer<byte[]> dataConsumer = new BasicAsyncEntityConsumer();
    return new BasicRequestConsumer<>(dataConsumer);
}
```

I was able to gain access to the POST request body using `message.getBody()`.  The GET branch of the if is to work around an embedded HTTP client that seems to fail if I use a `BasicAsyncEntityConsumer` with a GET.